# My WordPress website is loading slowly, especially on Apple devices

Tags: wordpress

I've got a WordPress website I'm currently working on. It was loading extremely fast just a couple days ago, then got extremely slow all of a sudden.

I've tried disabling plugins, removing large elements from the homepage (videos and such), and upgrading the server to see if that would help. This problem is especially noticeable on iPhones and in the Safari web browser.

I'm not really entirely sure what I should be asking, but the site can be found at https://dev.kwonkwon.com/ - if anyone can provide any sort of advice or is able to point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The usual suspects for improving WordPress page loads are to add caching (the W3 Total Cache plugin is a good option) and to combine & minify JS and CSS assets (I like Fast Velocity Minify). From there, you can use [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to drill into the specific things that are still slow.

Comment: Yes the Preloader is taking it's time :) If you are in a production phase, it's better you use a cache plugin compatible with your server. And like mentioned above, Google Page Speed is good and you could Have a look here too : https://gtmetrix.com/reports/dev.kwonkwon.com/XL3fvymX

Answer (score 0):

**You can optimize your site:**
check your website here ***https://gtmetrix.com*** and follow the suggestions, it is useful.
I have checked your website, you really need to optimize your images.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite surprised because I just look at your website. A website like this should be loaded in under 3 seconds.
[Check out your website test results here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvOju.jpg)

- First, You need to optimize your images. Scale the images to a size that you are using and use tinypng.com for compression if you do not know how to use Photoshop.
- Second, Use a cache plugin. You can test all of them and see which one suits the best. W3 Total Cache is ok.
- Third, Revslider is the worst. Try not using it. You can also add a simple background.